# npm unable to install scrypt. node-gyp rebuild

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, blockchain, scrypt

I want to run a blockchain application, but I got this error.

> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>       npm ERR! errno 1
>       npm ERR! scrypt@6.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
>       npm ERR! Exit status 1
>       npm ERR! 
>       npm ERR! Failed at the scrypt@6.0.3 install script.
>       npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm.

There is likely additional logging output above.

I have tried deleting node_modules, `npm` cache verify and `npm install` again. I have uninstalled and reinstalled `npm` and `nodejs`. My `npm` version is `6.12.0` and `node` version `v12.13.0`

Comment: I found this issue on Github. You can see the discussion and a response for a Linux system as well: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1066#issuecomment-438114907

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1066#issuecomment-338841841

From this link:

> I've solved this using the following steps

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
node-gyp configure --msvs_version=2015
npm config set python /path/to/executable/python2.7
npm install web3 --save
```

---

And also, I think that you can follow steps to fix node-gyp:

https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp

Comment: SO should I do linux-build-tools if I am running this on linux?

Comment: @Geek I'm not sure about that. You should try. Who knows, It may work.

Answer (score 0):

Believe or not, 
use: sudo npm ... 
It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old one, but for anyone hung on this one now, what solved this for me was downgrading to node v10.24.1 & npm v6.14.12. Seems to be an issue with newer node versions.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get remove -y gyp
sudo apt-get install -y curl bzip2 build-essential g++ python3 git make gcc gcc-multilib node-gyp
sudo apt-get install -y pkg-config xserver-xorg-dev libxext-dev pkg-config libxi-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libglew-dev
sudo npm install prebuild-install node-pre-gyp node-gyp -g
```

if show already exist then  use --force flag while installing npm package

if then also not solve then try install package using  "sudo npm i "

for more information see https://github.com/zodern/meteor-up/issues/683